# Problem with dependencies gradle exception

Tags: java, android

What the hell is this? I know that I have to upgrade something within my app dependencies but it does not point out what and where!!

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.5,16.0.5], [16.0.4,16.0.4], [16.3.0,16.3.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I added the following dependencies for admob ads and gave me that error :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

Project level gradle :

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.genesisbc.marketplace"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please provide enough of your `build.gradle` file that we can replicate this issue ourselves (even if it means all dependencies).

Comment: Done. Please check edit